# Linux vagrantlucid32 make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile, vagrant, ubuntu-10.04, lucid

When I run the  `make all` command  I keep getting:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

[Here is a link to the book I'm following](https://tfetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/how-to-create-an-operating-system.pdf) read pages 6-7 maybe this can help solve the problem.

On:

Linux vagrantlucid32 2.6.32-73-generic-pae #140-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 10 15:30:51 UTC 2015 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Does anyone know why I keep getting this? Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: `make all` doesn't "set up a makefile".  There's no `make` command that will set up a makefile for you.  You have to create a makefile yourself (using a text editor), then `make` will _execute_ that makefile.  The command `make all` says, "read in the current makefile, then run the commands needed to make the `all` target up to date."  If you're getting an error "No rule to make target 'all'", then either you don't have a makefile at all or the one you do have doesn't describe how to build the `all` target.

Comment: BTW, Ubuntu 10.04 really?  That's... pretty old.